# How can I check if a visitor can read a post?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, logging

I know how to check capabilities for logged in users, with

```
$can_read = current_user_can('read',$post->ID);
```

But the above code returnes false when the user is not logged.
So how can I check if the visitor has access to it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.9/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L692-L694
`current_user_can()` returns `false` because in 1st parameter `wp_get_current_user()` is impossible to have if the user is not connected.
You should take the problem on the other xay, by default it's readable and if content must be seen by some user logged in or other criterias, then change the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Vistors usually always have the rights to access a post. Only exceptions that I know are drafts, password protected posts or post_types that are not public accessable.

You could use [get_post_status()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/) and [post_password_required()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/)

Comment: ...or should I run a WP_Query instead of my current get_post() ?